# Подключение Wi-Fi в Linux

Tags: linux

Доброго времени суток, скачал, установил linux mint (2010года выпуска) на ноутбук hp620.Всем доволен, только выхода в сеть нет: при PPOP соединении userpoint требует, wifi не    подключается (не видит и индикатор на клавиатуре не включается).

Возможно подсказать решение с учетом моего отсутствия опыта работы в linux?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в стандартной поставке нет нужных драйверов для WiFi модуля ноутбука. Подключитесь к проводной сети и попробуйте обновиться

```
sudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get upgrade
```

Дальше выполните команду

```
nm-tool
```

и посмотрите, есть ли строка "State: connected". Если есть, проверьте список сетей для подключения и выберите интересующую. Если нет, то выполните команду

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

Есть шанс, что поможет.

Comment: Как уже писалось, при попытке проводного соединения (PPOP) просит   USERPOINT. П.С. и провайдер не в курсе, что это.

Answer (score 0):

вообще в минте (в кате точно) есть такая штука как установка драйверов Винды для беспроводных устройств. Я ни разу не пользовался ( у меня все правильно встает ), но попробуйте хоть вы. Находится в центре управления